# After Insert Trigger terminate when error

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have an `After Insert` trigger which is supposed to insert first, then do insert another table. But when any error occurs for inserting data in another table the all transaction terminated. I want to insert 1st data in base table whether the trigger fire successfully or not.

This is my code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Insert_Teacher_Active_LC]
   ON  [dbo].[Teacher_Profile]
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    MERGE [ROSC].[dbo].[Active_LC] as d
    USING (SELECT 
              DistrictID, upazilaID, LCID, LCVisitYr, Trimister,
              CASE WHEN (TcrPres = 1 AND TcrMtchLCProf = 1) 
                   THEN 1 ELSE 0 
              END AS TcrRpls
           FROM INSERTED) AS s ON s.DistrictID = d.DistrictID 
                                AND s.upazilaID = d.upazilaID 
                                AND s.LCID = d.LCID 
                                AND s.LCVisitYr = d.EduYr

    WHEN MATCHED THEN
       UPDATE 
         SET Trimister = s.Trimister, Tcr_Replace = s.TcrRpls

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT(DistrictID, UpazilaID, LCID, EduYr, Trimister, Tcr_Replace)
        VALUES(DistrictID, UpazilaID, LCID, LCVisitYr, Trimister, TcrRpls);

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
END
```